# How to sum multiple row values with groupby using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given below is a pyspark dataframe and I need to sum the row values with groupby

```
load_dt|org_cntry|sum(srv_curr_vo_qty_accs_mthd)|sum(srv_curr_bb_qty_accs_mthd)|sum(srv_curr_tv_qty_accs_mthd)|
+-------------------+---------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|2021-12-06 00:00:00|     null|                           NaN|                           NaN|                           NaN|
|2021-12-06 00:00:00|   PANAMA|                      360126.0|                      214229.0|                      207950.0|
```

**condition:**

1.groupby(load_dt,org_cntry)

2.sum row values (sum(srv_curr_vo_qty_accs_mthd)|sum(srv_curr_bb_qty_accs_mthd)|sum(srv_curr_tv_qty_accs_mthd)|

**expected output**

```
load_dt     org_cntry   total_sum
2021-12-06  Panama       782305
```

Comment: Could you add what is the expected output?

Comment: yes, I added the expected output. Basically it should add the row values based on groupby condition

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Spark2.4+ Higher order functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample dataframe
#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
#|            load_dt|org_cntry|      s1|      s2|      s3|
#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+
#|2021-12-06 00:00:00|   PANAMA|360126.0|214229.0|207950.0|
#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+

#create array from sum columns then add all the array elements.
df.selectExpr("*", "AGGREGATE(array(s1,s2,s3), cast(0 as double), (x, y) -> x + y) total_sum").show()

#using withColumn
df.withColumn("total_sum", expr("AGGREGATE(array(s1,s2,s3), cast(0 as double), (x, y) -> x + y)")).show()

#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
#|            load_dt|org_cntry|      s1|      s2|      s3|total_sum|
#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
#|2021-12-06 00:00:00|   PANAMA|360126.0|214229.0|207950.0| 782305.0|
#+-------------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Answer (score 2):

simply sum(+) your result :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.groupBy("load_dt", "org_cntry").agg(
    (
        F.sum("srv_curr_vo_qty_accs_mthd")
        + F.sum("srv_curr_bb_qty_accs_mthd")
        + F.sum("srv_curr_tv_qty_accs_mthd")
    ).alias("total_sum")
)
```

Comment: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'groupBy' I'm getting this error

Comment: I've tried the above code, but I'm getting the above error. Can you pls help me on this @Steven

Comment: [`groupBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.groupBy) is a method of dataframe ... so I do not understand why you have this error ...

Comment: @PavithraKannan Are you using a pandas dataframe or a spark dataframe ?